# Clicking on the tab to navigate to salesforce pages

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-tab

I have a lwc component with the vertical tabs as below. On click of each of these tabs, I want to render/navigate to the specific salesforce page. Example to the create account.
I am trying below , however it is failing. Is below the correct way of doing it or any alternative approach?

```
 <template>
    <lightning-tabset variant="vertical">
                <template for:each={tabs} for:item="tab">
                    <lightning-tab label={tab} key={tab} onactive={tabChangeHandler}>
                    </lightning-tab>    
                </template>
     </lightning-tabset>
 </template>
```

JS File -

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class VerticalNavLWC extends LightningElement {
//  Other codes
tabChangeHandler(){
     // Opens the new Account record modal
        // to create an Account.
        console.log('Inside tab change handler');
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
         type: 'standard__objectPage',
         attributes: {
             objectApiName: 'Account',
             actionName: 'new'
         }
     }); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the NavigationMixin to the component's base class to gain access to its APIs as stated in the documentation:

```
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class MyCustomElement extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {}
```

[NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation)